# Flutter Login with Facebook returns build error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I was integrating login with facebook option to my flutter app.

I used

**firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5**

**flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1**

After i connect firebase the app was running without any error. But flutter run gives this error when i intergrate the **flutter_facebook_login** plugin.

**I added these lines to my manifest.xml file**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**And I created strings.xml file in app->src->main->res->values**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><resources><string name="app_name">Your App Name here.</string>

<string name="facebook_app_id">157892568845063</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb157892568845063</string></resources>
```

Here is the implementaion

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isLogged = false;

  Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook() async{
      var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
      var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

      debugPrint(result.status.toString());
  }
```

**here is the error i get**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note :  Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 and Dart 2.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your flutter_facebook_login package to 2.0.0 or up as mentioned in docs of the package.

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
```

or install lastest one

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

Its mentioned in docs to use this package with androidX you need to have version 2.0.0 or above.

Comment: thank you I've upgraded and everything works fine now